# how to make sure the file name is quoted when it has space

Tags: c#, .net

When use Process.startInfo.Arguments, I have filename as one of the argument,

StartInfo.Arguments = filename

I am wondering how to make sure it is correct in the case that filename is "test test".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would simply *always* quote it; since "test" is valid too.

I don't know if there is inbuilt file escaping anywhere, but

```
procStart.Arguments = "blah blip -in \"" + filePath + "\" more args";
```

should do...

If you wanted you could get fancy with checking the input string (`filePath` above), but it probably isn't worth checking the edge-cases. For the same reason that if I'm writing TSQL over an unknown table, I'd always add explicit `[` / `]` (without bothering to check if it needs it).

Comment: Will the build-in class do that for us? Just like when you are using `SqlCommand` with parameters, you don't need to worry about the `'` char in an NVARCHAR parameter's value.

Comment: @Danny - that is because **in a parameter** there *is* no escaping - you send the literal value; but in `.Arguments` you are building an unstructured string.

Comment: You are correct Marc, but the syntax looks ugly. I also want to know if there is built-in function

Comment: @user: the builtin functions just normalize paths, there's nothing that I know of for enquoting a string.

Comment: @user496949 well, if it is just space you want to check, then maybe `path.Contains(" ") ? ("\"" + path + "\"") : path` - but I worry about other characters (`<` maybe ?)

Comment: @user the value you give is just a string value. It does not become a path until the executing program interprets it that as such. How's the class (ProcessStart) to know if it's a literal value where adding " would be an error or if it's actually a file path. The best it can do is say it's probably a filepath. But that's not really enough